# wget inside exec does not generate any output or saves the webpage

Tags: php, exec, wget

I'm working on a small, personal project that can save an entire webpage onto my local disk with PHP with wget.

Basically when I pass an URL, it should save the webpage, fixing the URLs and images by this:

```
exec('cd application/collection; wget -k -p --user-agent=Firefox/11.0 google.com, $output', $return);

print_r($output); // Array( )
print_r($return); // 0
```

Strangely I get no output, nothing is saved in the directory (it's the correct directory, I can confirm). My localhost is running the user `_www`, how can I allow to save the webpage using wget via PHP's exec function?

I can't use `file_get_contents` because it does not fix the URLs and images.

Comment: Are you trying this on two different servers? Is wget in your PATH on both, if so?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

exec('cd application/collection; /usr/bin/wget -k -p --user-agent="Firefox/11.0" "http://www.google.com"', $output, $return);

Comment: I get no output, but the return is now `127`.

Comment: It's working correctly on my environment.Try using absolute paths.

Comment: I did, both doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved this but google redirect me to this Q, so, for anyone else:

You need to redirect stderr to stdout: 2>&1

```
exec('cd application/collection; wget -k -p --user-agent=Firefox/11.0
google.com 2>&1', $output, $return);
print_r($output); 
print_r($return);
```